Query transpose lookup - returning results
Background:
Google Sheets being used.
I have large (>10k rows), of unorganized sheets of data with ID's and values that I am trying to return values for given ID's. I have no ability to order the data, nor would it be time efficient to do so (I suspect).
Data is in the format of:



BlueprintID
ActivityID
MaterialID
Quantity




1
1
50
1


2
2
51
2



But may be unordered within that sheet of data, eg:



BlueprintID
ActivityID
MaterialID
Quantity




5
3
64
13


1
1
22
5



Problem:
I am looking up values into another sheet to perform math / finance operations on the output.
I have control over this sheet that I am working within.
My current format for data is as follows:



ItemID
MaterialID - 1
MaterialID - 2
MaterialID - 3
MaterialID - n




1






2






3







I have written the following formula to look up material values for given ItemID's / MatierialID's:
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Materials!A:D,"Select D where A matches '"&QUERY(Items!A:C,"Select A where C matches '"&ItemID&"'",0)&"' and B = 1",0))

Explanation of Code:
For a given ItemID, the Item's table is queried to return a BlueprintID.
The BlueprintID is used in the materials table to select given material values where the blueprint ID is a match.
Example raw output:
|  80000     |  15000    |   5000   |  1000  |
However the output is dependent on the order of values within the Materials table.
So can look like:
|  1000 | 5000  |  15000    |  30000  |
Question:
Can my formula be re-written or amended in a way to account for only returning values in the order specified by the MaterialID table I am returning values into.
The confounding issue is that not all items use all materials.
There may be multiple gaps between different material ID's
My thoughts:
Amend query / transpose to return results ordered by referencing the materialID's.
I suspect an index / match may be useful but I am hitting a bit of road block in terms of writing a new formula.
Any help is appreciated!
What I have done - See above. Reviewed briefly:
Wrote the following formula:
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Materials!A:D,"Select D where A matches '"&QUERY(Items!A:C,"Select A where C matches '"&ItemID&"'",0)&"' and B = 1",0))
Which returns correct values but not in the correct order as the primary sheets containing raw data is unordered.
Additionally, not all items require all materials, and some Material ID's may be skipped.

I don't know if I fully understand your scenario; but I suggest you dig in FILTER to get the values in the original order:
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Materials!D:D,  Materials!A:A=QUERY(Items!A:C,"Select A where C matches '"&ItemID&"'",0),  Materials!B:B=1))

You could also convert your inner QUERY (the one from Items! sheet) into another FILTER formula, but if it's retreiving the correct value, then that would be no problem
